# Mac OS Media Key is not working

Tags: macos, google-chrome, apple-silicon, apple-music

As to tiles. I try to use Media key (prev track, play/stop, next track). I not working in any APP (such as apple music chrome). When I first use my macbook to now. I use Mac OS 12 to 14, is always not working.

I also use `MediaForwarder`. It work it. But is no good. Such as only control specific APP. Can't control Chrome.

I asking other user. They can use Media key control chrome and Music. I try to create new User in my mac. Fortunately, Media key is working in new user.

By the way, the media keys work on parallel desktop in Win11. It's very irritating and ridiculous ;)

I'd like to know who's hogging the  media keys. I try to reset `coreaudiod` and delete driver about app created. It's no effects.

Is there any software that can check which software or tool is using the Media key? I'm trying to get him to work by troubleshooting the error, rather than using a third party tool. Because reset the System is more setup to me. I worry time machine is not all cover my Software config. I dont want to lose anything data.

Thanks your any communication!